# Visual Studio 2019 can't override CodeStyle option

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2019, text-editor

i am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.6.5;

The problem is that: when i go to
Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > General
if i want to change the "Severity" of a line, the edges of the box of the current Sevrity becomes red. (maybe some problems occurs)
Infact, after I press "ok" button to confirm, it resets all value that i have changed.

this image shows the setting that i changed: that drop down button was "Refactoring only", but I want "Suggestions".
[image]

[there](https://youtu.be/qv6ZflueASY?t=1140) a link to a YouTube video that I was watching; the link shows what I want to do.
(link directly to the minute 19:00)

Thanks!